# Sorted function in Python not returning expected result

Tags: python

I am learning programming in python. I do not have experience in programming and learning. I am writing a program in python, where a user adds a company name and it is alphabetically sorted and displayed. Then a user enters a letter and if the company name starts with that letter, then that company(ies) name should display. I tried and failing to do so.
Here is what I have written so far..

```
company_name_list = []
new_name = ""
while new_name != 'quit':
    new_name = input("enter your company name, or enter quit to exit: ")
    if new_name != 'quit':
        company_name_list.append(new_name)
        print("List of companies name: " + str(company_name_list))
    else:
        print("Thanks for your information. See you later.")
        exit()
    sorted_list = sorted(company_name_list)
    print("Sorted list: " + str(company_name_list))
    # first_letter = 'a'
    first_letter = input("enter first letter for your company: ")
    # for company in range(0, len(company_name) + 1):
    for company in range(1, len(sorted_list) + 1):
        # print("company")
        # first_letter = input("enter first letter for your company")
        if str(company).startswith(first_letter):
            print("company_name: " + str(company))
        else:
            print("Cannot find the company with letter: " + str(first_letter))
        break
```

This is what I am seeing when I enter the letter for the company name to filter out

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 203.7148.72)
enter your company name, or enter quit to exit: >? yahoo
List of companies name: ['yahoo']
Sorted list: ['yahoo']
enter first letter for your company: >? t
Cannot find the company with letter: t
enter your company name, or enter quit to exit: >? google
List of companies name: ['yahoo', 'google']
Sorted list: ['google', 'yahoo']
enter first letter for your company: >? h
Cannot find the company with letter: h
enter your company name, or enter quit to exit: >? juniper
List of companies name: ['yahoo', 'google', 'juniper']
Sorted list: ['google', 'juniper', 'yahoo']
enter first letter for your company: >? y
Cannot find the company with letter: y
enter your company name, or enter quit to exit:
```

Even there is a company with name which starts with Y, its not finding it.

Comment: `print("Sorted list: " + str(company_name_list))` You save the sorted list in `sorted_list`, not `company_name_list`. In the future please explain exactly what does not work as expected

Comment: What your input, the desired and observed output?

Answer (score 0):

you are indeed beginner, i hope this will help you
i think it does exactly what you want

```
company_name_list = []
command = "" # make your names more readable
while True: # no need for check
    command = input("enter your company name, or enter quit to exit: ")
    if command != 'quit':
        company_name_list.append(command)
        print("List of companies name: " + str(company_name_list))
    else:
        print("Thanks for your information. See you later.")
        exit()

    sorted_list = sorted(company_name_list)
    print("Sorted list: " + str(sorted_list)) # print the correct thing

    first_letter = input("enter first letter for your company: ")
    found = False #this is how you figure out whether condition in loop happened, you just switch a bool
    for company in sorted_list:
        if company.startswith(first_letter):
            print("company_name: " + company)
            found = True 

    if not found: # found is false so no companies were printed
        print("Cannot find the company with letter: " + first_letter)
```